# Getting a Clients.findById is not a function error and don't know why

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, redux

I have an api for data storage and retrieval from a MS SQL database. I can retrieve all of the clients from the database but when I try to extract just a single client I get *Clients.findById is not a function*.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
// Fetch all Clients
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Clients.findAll().then(clients => {
        // Send all Clients to Client
        res.send(clients);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
    })
};

// Find a Customer by Id
exports.findById = (req, res) => {
    Clients.findById(req.params.id).then(client => {
        res.send(client);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
    })
};
```

...

When I test this in Postman using the url of *http://localhost:8080/api/clients/0*

I get the error. I'm not sure why the findAll works and the findById doesn't.

Comment: Can you share clients model

Comment: //client.model.js

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
 const Client = sequelize.define('client', {
  company: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  contact: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  phone: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  email: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
 });

 return Client;
}

Comment: which database are you use ?

Comment: I’m using a local MS SQL database but in the end transition to an Enterprise MS SQL Server